# How to read a local file in Javascript (Running from an Electron App)

Tags: javascript, file, methods, io, electron

I have been searching for over an hour or so, and I cant find an answer to my question. Is there a way to get the text from a local file, using just a plain old file URL?

I have found numerous ways to read a file via file input HTML tag, but I have had an incredible pain, finding a code example that can find a file, on my PC, using just plain old JS.

The code will be inside an electron application.

I need code examples. Something like this:

```
readFile("file:\\\\C:\path\to\file.txt","text/plain");

readFile(url,mimetype){
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reading a file is done using node and is not dependent on electron
2. Where you have the code for creating a window add this code

```
const fs = require("fs");

function readFile(fileURL,mimeType){
   //readfile does not accept the file:\\\ thing, so we remove it
   const pathToFile = fileURL.replace("file:\\\\",'');

   fs.readFile(pathToFile,mimeType,(err,contents)=>{
     if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
     }
     console.log(contents);
   })
}

readFile('C:\\Users\\<userAccount>\\Documents\\test.txt','utf8')
//If your on windows you'll need to use double backslashes for the paths
//here's an example regex to do that

pathToFile = pathToFile.replace(/\\/,'\\\\')
```

Answer (score 22):

If you want to read a file in Electron, you have to understand the various parts of an Electron app. In *short*, there is a **main** process and a **renderer** process. The main process has and is given all control to use node modules, such as the [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module that can read files. The renderer process should not have access to the `fs` module, but instead anytime it needs to use the `fs` module, it should ask the main process to use `fs`, and then return the result.

> FYI the renderer process is the web page, the visible part of your Electron app.

This communication is called IPC (inter-process communication). The flow is:

1. Renderer process sends a message to the main process over IPC
2. The main process hears the message, and then reads a file with `fs`
3. The contents/result are sent back via IPC to the renderer process
4. The renderer process now can do what it wants with the data from the file

A very rough example is below.

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // Called when message received from main process
        window.api.receive("fromMain", (data) => {
            console.log(`Received ${data} from main process`);
        });

        // Send a message to the main process
        window.api.send("toMain", "some data");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```js
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  ipcMain
} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;

async function createWindow() {

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false, // is default value after Electron v5
      contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
      enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // use a preload script
    }
  });

  // Load app
  win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"));

  // rest of code..
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

ipcMain.on("toMain", (event, args) => {
  fs.readFile("path/to/file", (error, data) => {
    // Do something with file contents

    // Send result back to renderer process
    win.webContents.send("fromMain", responseObj);
  });
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of a popular [secure electron template](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template), and have wrote a [specific guide](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/docs/newtoelectron.md) on how to use `fs` to read a file in an Electron app. I hope you give it a read because it has additional information there.

Comment: What is the area regarding exposeInMainWorld doing? It's kind of missing explanation

Comment: `exposeInMainWorld` is just allowing the functions we define (the functions will exist on the `window`, ie. `window.api.send`) to exist in the renderer/view processes.

Comment: @reZach That [new to electron](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/docs/newtoelectron.md) guide is awesome - first time that I managed to understand what IPC does.

Comment: I am glad it was helpful for you @icc97

Answer (score -3):

if im not mistaken, using something like this should work with the fs module.

```
fs.readFileSync("/path/to/file.txt");
```

Comment: That dosent seem to work when I try it within a web browser... I am not familiar with FS, is there something i need to do to import FS?

Comment: yeah its a node package "file-system"  

here's the documentation on it https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-system.